# Generating non-homogeneous poisson process events via 'poisson' package in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the function `nhpp.sim()` in "poisson" package in R, however, the returned values I'm getting are out of the range of 24 hours. The function method is `nhpp.sim(rate, num.events, prob.func, num.sims = 1, t0 = 0, prepend.t0 = T)` 
From what I understood, rate is the average value between event times, num.events is the number of events, and prob.func is the intensity function (the probability of the event in that time segment). I am trying to simulate 10 events in 24 hours based on the intensity function

```
intensity  <- function(t) {    
  if (t >= 0 && t < 1) {lambda = 0.0100456621004566}   
  else if (t >= 1 && t < 2) {lambda = 0.00650684931506849}    
  else if (t >= 2 && t < 3) {lambda = 0.00707762557077626}        
.

. 

.  
else if (t >= 23 && t < 24) {lambda = 0.0219178082191781}    
  else if (t >= 24) {lambda = 0}

  return(lambda)    
}
```

then I call the function by: `nhpp.sim(0.4316, 10, prob.func=intensity,1,0,24)`
and the event times I am getting are out of the 24-hour barrier, why is that?